# How to format axes in R, year and months

Tags: r, plot

I have the following dataset

```
1890 mar 0.4
1890 apr 0.8
1890 may 1.0
...
1989 jan 0.2
1989 feb 0.4
1989 mar 0.5
```

How can I make a line plot in [R](http://www.r-project.org/) with on the x-axis the year, displayed every 5 years?

My problem is not so much making the plot, but getting to display only the years I want, and place them on the beginning of that year. So I don't want a tick on April but on January.

Comment: R is a statistical computing environment. Click for example on the r tag. I will add a link to their homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
# create some data
set.seed(1)
tmp <- seq(as.POSIXct("1890-03-01", tz="GMT"),
           as.POSIXct("1920-03-01", tz="GMT"),
           by="month")
df <- data.frame(date=tmp,
                 val=rnorm(length(tmp)))

# plot data
plot(df$date, df$val, xaxt="n")
tickpos <- seq(as.POSIXct("1890-01-01", tz="GMT"),
               as.POSIXct("1920-01-01", tz="GMT"),
               by="5 years")
axis.POSIXct(side=1, at=tickpos)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

You get what rcs (correctly !) suggested by default using [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo) as plot with lines and the same axis:

```
R> library(zoo)
R> zdf <- zoo(df$val, order.by=df$date)
R> plot(zdf)
R>
```

The `help(plot.zoo)` examples show to do fancier date indexing, essentially what rcs showed you but with an additional formatting via, say,

```
R> fmt <- "%Y-%m"  ## year-mon
R> txt <- format(index(zdf), fmt)
R> plot(zdf, xaxt='n')
R> axis(side=1, at=index(zdf), lab=txt)
R>
```

If you subset `at` and `lab` you get fewer ticks too.